# An unhandled exception occurred: The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'

Tags: angular

If you are getting the error `An unhandled exception occurred: The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'.` or some variation of that while using `ng build` or `ng deploy`, then here is the solution that worked for me (scroll down).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Go into your `angular.json` file
2. In that file, follow the path projects -> architect -> build -> options
3. Change `"buildOptimizer"` to `true` and add `"aot"` to `true` as well

The above commands should work now.

**ADDON**: If you have that problem with `ng serve` or `ng test`, you could try replacing `build` in step 2 with `serve` or `test` respectively (Disclaimer: I have not tested that).

Comment: Looks like someone forgot to do `ng update` for our repo. This resolved it for us.

Comment: In our case, we needed deleting package-lock.json and node_modules, then npm i...

Comment: none worked for me. I get error from `ng serve`

Answer (score 12):

When I upgrade from angular 11 to angular 13 I see this error during command `ng serve`. To fix it I created a brand new angular project with the "@angular/cli" and imitate the `angular.json` of the new project.

inside `angular.json` `projects>MY_PROJECT_NAME>architect>build>configurations` added a `development` with json

```
"development": {
  "buildOptimizer": false,
  "optimization": false,
  "vendorChunk": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": true
}
```

under `...serve>configurations` added

```
"development": {
  "browserTarget": "hasap:build:development"
}
```

under `...serve>` added `"defaultConfiguration": "development"`

You can see the details of changes in `angular.json` from my commit https://github.com/canbax/hasap/commit/9c0fc95fc244d35b2d7ee70c7048f6b38bd213b5

Comment: I had same problem on my side and use different configuration on `angular.json` solve it! Thanks a Million!

Answer (score 3):

you need to enable AOT compilation in your angular.json

change it to true

build{
"aot": true,
...
}

Answer (score 2):

I was facing that exact error message but in my case I was trying to set up Cypress in my Angular project.

I could solve the problem by adding the following config in both *projects.private-sellers-spa.architect.**cypress-open**.options* and *projects.private-sellers-spa.architect.**cypress-run**.options*, at angular.json, as follows:

```
"buildOptimizer": true,
"aot": true
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the production configuration to serve my project

```
 ng serve -o --ssl true --configuration production
```

This will use the buildOptimizer and the aot issue.